# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: php, database, laravel, phpmyadmin, database-migration

Please help me with this. I want to delete, refresh and reset my migration and my db but still stuck with this error.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` = 1 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null)
```

Comment: Better check the `posts` table has `user_id`

Comment: Does this issue occur when migrating? If so, it would be a good idea to show the migration that's not working.

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen You might as well make your comment as an answer. I saw you beat me by about 9 hours.

Comment: @YahyaUddin Sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says `user_id` column is not in `posts` table. Check if it is available in the `posts` table.

If you have that column and still throwing an error, please update your question with the `posts` table migrations and the **Eloquent** query you are trying to execute.